# Leaflet: Changing map center when select is change

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with a `select`. The `select` contains location with a coordinates as a value.

When I change the `select` the map should reload and change the map center depending on the value of the select.

Here's my code:

```js
var coor =[11.5303, 122.6842];
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView(coor, 13);

              L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
maxZoom: 18,

id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);


 mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>


<div style="border:1px solid grey; width:500px;height:310px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:20px;">
<select id="loc" onchange="change_map()">
    <option value="[11.5529, 122.7407]">Roxas City</option>
    <option value="[11.5303, 122.6842]">Ivisan</option>
</select>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't do what you want using `value = "[11.5529, 122.7407]"` in the option value.

First, change the `value` of the `select` tag. For example:

```
<select id="loc" onchange="change_map()">
    <option value="1">Roxas City</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Ivisan</option>
</select>
```

In your function `onchange` do this:

```
// onchange function (this format makes the function global)
window.change_map = function(){
    // Get the select element
    var e = document.getElementById("loc");
    // Get the value of the selected index
    var v = e.value;

    // Verify the value and set the map to the new center
    if( v == "1" ){ mymap.setView([11.5529, 122.7407], zoom); }
    else if( v == "2" ) { mymap.setView([11.5303, 122.6842], zoom); }
}
```

Here's the **[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/thiagobsouza/m09t5at0/5/)**.

Any other suggestion will be apreciated.

Hope I was helpful.

Comment: Its alright if its different from my code. . and thanks for the answer. it works.=)